# Highlighting GeoJSON components based on common feature properties

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I have a GeoJSON map. It's a map of a country, which is made up of states, which are in turn made up of sub-state regions.

I can create a Leaflet map where I can highlight (in this case 'orange') the sub-state regions as the cursor touches them. I would like to simultaneously highlight other sub-state regions (in a different colour) that are in the same state as the initial region (ie. I want to highlight the selected sub-state region one colour, and the remainder of the state another colour).

I think I need to put the new bit of code at the comment 'new bit of code here', but I don't know how to select the other elements in the geojson that ARE NOT the one currently selected, but that still have the feature property `STATE_NAME16 == tmp`.

```
geojson = L.geoJson(States_Data, {

    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.on('mouseover', function () {
          var tmp = feature.properties.STATE_NAME16 ;

          this.setStyle({
            'fillColor': 'orange'
          });

          //[new bit of code here]

        });

    }


}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to style GeoJSON features with Leaflet. The first is as you are doing now: passing a static object with a style defined as a JSON object. The alternative is to **define a function that takes a feature, and returns a style**. Something like the following would highlight red in the first case (sub-state), then blue (same state), and finally null (everything else) as a fallback.

```javascript
var style = function(feature) {
  if (feature.properties.subStateRegion == hovered_sub_state_region) return {'fill-color': 'red'}
  if (feature.properties.state == hovered_state) return {'fill-color': 'blue'}
  return {'fill-color': null}
})
```

Then it's a matter of getting your application to update the `hovered_sub_state_region` and `hovered_state` state variables in your hover handler. This could be done by mutating a global variable, or otherwise with some form of state management (e.g. `setState` in React). Possibly you will need to trigger a re-render, with `redraw` or `setStyle` (passing that `style` variable); at this point it depends on how you have put together your application.

Check out the Options > `style` part of the Leaflet GeoJSON docs: https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/